# JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out

Tags: java, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly

when I run my Code I always get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out.
```

I try to connect to my JBOSS Eap 7.

If I try it in Powershell, connecting to **remote://127.0.0.1:9990** doesn't work but connecting to **remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990** does work. So I think I have to change the protocol, but I don't know how.

```
ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9990);

    ModelNode operation = new ModelNode();
    operation.get("address").add("deployment", "*");
    operation.get("operation").set("read-attribute");
    operation.get("name").set("name");

    ModelNode result = client.execute(operation);
```

standalone.xml:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't look like a protocol issue. did you define a native interface in standalone.xml?
In new versions of WildFly, this is depreciated but may work in your case. Refer documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The%20native%20management%20API.html

It also talks about having an authentication layer.