# Java Method to get a List of all deployed applications on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly

i need your help. I need to get a List of all deployed applications on a Jboss server. Best would be if I would get a List of the URL's of the applications. I don't know how to do this.
I tried it but I had a Problem. [JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67316151/15792588)

Is there any way to get the URL's of the deployed applications?

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I'm using JBoss EAP 7.3.3.GA

Comment: Given the message id on your other question that looks like an older version of JBoss EAP you're attempting to connect to. Are you just wanting the context root for each deployment?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes the context root would be enough

Comment: Are you sure you're using JBoss EAP 7.3.3? That "JBAS012144" is from an older version of JBoss AS 7.x or JBoss EAP 6.x.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The version.txt in my jboss-eap-7 folder says: Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.3.3.GA

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Please also take a look at this. This is another method I tried. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401791/jbrem000202-abrupt-close-on-remoting-connection-58fb662d-to-127-0-0-19990

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use JBoss CLI Java API to query JBoss in order to get the list of all deployments, and then for each of them, use another command to get its url.

Here is an example (tested on Wildfly 20):

```
import org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext;
import org.jboss.as.cli.scriptsupport.CLI;
import org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient;
import org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode;

...

CLI cli = CLI.newInstance();
cli.connect();  // *Local* connection - use cli.connext(...) for *remote* connection
CommandContext ctx = cli.getCommandContext();
ModelControllerClient client = ctx.getModelControllerClient();

// Get all deployed webapps
ModelNode cliCommand = ctx.buildRequest("deployment-info");             
ModelNode response = client.execute(cliCommand);
ModelNode result = response.get("result");
LOG.trace("CLI response: {}", result.toJSONString(false) );
Set<String> webapps = result.keys();

// Get context path of a particular webapp
String webapp = "..."; 
String s = String.format("/deployment=%s/subsystem=undertow:read-attribute(name=context-root)", webapp);
ModelNode cliCommand = ctx.buildRequest(s); 
ModelControllerClient client = ctx.getModelControllerClient();
ModelNode response = client.execute(cliCommand);        
String path = response.get("result").asString();
...
cli.disconnect();
```

Comment: I get the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize command context. Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[6,1]                      Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:cli:3.3}jboss-cli'

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Note that if you've got some EAR's you might need to change it a bit.

```java
public static Map<String, String> getDeployments() throws IOException {
    final Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)) {
        final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("deployment", "*", "subsystem", "undertow");
        final ModelNode op = Operations.createReadAttributeOperation(address, "context-root");
        final ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
        if (!Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
        }

        final List<ModelNode> deployments = Operations.readResult(result).asList();
        for (ModelNode deployment : deployments) {
            final ModelNode deploymentAddress = Operations.getOperationAddress(deployment);
            if (deploymentAddress.isDefined()) {
                final String deploymentName = deploymentAddress.asPropertyList().get(0).getValue().asString();
                final String contextRoot = Operations.readResult(deployment).asString();
                map.put(deploymentName, contextRoot);
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I get the message: The method createAddress(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type Operations.  I use import org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.Operations;

Comment: What version of the `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller-client` are you using? Either way using you can create the address with a `ModelNode` directly. This is how it's done in the `Operations` utility https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/bd300d053971c441b93677c9aa346406f3f628ee/controller-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/controller/client/helpers/Operations.java#L121-L146.

Comment: I tried several versions. Which one should I use?

Comment: If you're using JBoss EAP 7.3.3 which ever version is supplied there would be the version to use. The version in 7.3.3. is 10.1.12.SP1-redhat-00001.

Comment: I forgot to add, if you want to use a community version the latest is 15.0.1.Final.